# Inclusion–exclusion: Matrices

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix that contains all the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n^2$ (each one appears one time). Count the number of $n \times n$ matrices $B$ that contain all the numbers $1,2,\ldots,n^2$ and don't have any row identical to some row in $A$, and don't have any column identical to some column in $A$.

I marked $R_i=\{\text{all the matrices with row }i\text{ identical to some row in }A\}$,
$C_i=\{\text{all the matrices with column }i\text{ identical to some column in }A\}$, and said that

$$\left|\bigcap_{i\in I} R_i\right|=\left|\bigcap_{i\in I} C_i\right|={n \choose |I|}\big(n^2-|I|n\big)!|I|!$$

and

$$\left|\bigcap_{i\in I} R_i\cap\bigcap_{j\in J} C_j\right|=\left(n^2-(|I|+|J|)n+|I||J|\right)!\;.$$

By the Inclusion–exclusion principle, I got  this answer:

$$(n^2)!+\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k\left[2{n \choose k}^2k!(n^2-kn)!+ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1}{n \choose i}{n \choose k-i}\big(n^2-kn+i(k-i)\big)!\right]\;.$$

Is this correct? Is there another way? Thanks

Comment: You can use `\left` and `\right` to make delimiters adjust to the size of their content, and you can use double dollar signs instead of single dollar signs to get displayed equations. It's very hard to read in this cramped style. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Sorry, my answer wasn't thought through; I've deleted it. But I think the point that it doesn't make sense to have $k$ run up to $2n$ with factors of $\binom nk$ in all terms is still right.

Comment: ok, thank you very much

Comment: I think I understand how you're counting now. I think $k$ should run up to $n$ instead of $2n$, and the first factor in the second sum should be $\binom ni$ instead of $\binom nk$?

Comment: yes, it's should be ${n \choose i}$,thanks. But I run up to $2n$ because there are intersections of size more than n between rows and columns

Comment: Ah, yes, with the $\binom nk$ factor replaced by $\binom ni$, that makes sense now.

Comment: There's a parenthesis missing at the end of the last equation (for the factorial), and a $\cap$ missing in the second displayed equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is  a slightly  different approach.  For  the nodes of  the poset
underlying  inclusion-exclusion   we  will  use   pairs  $(S,T)$  with
$S\subseteq [n]$  and $T\subseteq  [n]$ so that  $(S,T)\ne (\emptyset,
\emptyset)$ where $S$  gives the rows that agree with  some row of $A$
and $T$  the columns. Now  there are several possibilities  here. Note
that the rows and columns of  $A$ are all mutually distinct. If $T$ is
empty but not $S$ we choose  the $|S|$ rows and may permute them. Same
if $S$  is empty but not  $T.$ If neither  is empty there is  only one
possible assignment  namely an exact  match of the  corresponding rows
and  colums  from $A.$  Note  that  in the  later  case  we have  used
$n(|S|+|T|)-    |S|\times|T|$    elements.     We    thus    get    by
inclusion-exclusion

$$\sum_{S\ne\emptyset} (-1)^{|S|} {n\choose |S|}|S|! (n^2-|S|n)!
+ \sum_{T\ne\emptyset} (-1)^{|S|} {n\choose |T|}|T|! (n^2-|T|n)!
\\ + \sum_{S\ne\emptyset, T\ne \emptyset} 
(-1)^{|S|+|T|} (n^2 - n(|S|+|T|) +  |S|\times|T|)!.$$

Now at  this point we  need to compute  the weight on  a configuration
that has  exactly $p$ rows from  $A$ and $q$ columns.  With neither of
these empty we get

$$\sum_{p'=1}^p {p\choose p'} (-1)^{p'} +
\sum_{q'=1}^q {q\choose q'} (-1)^{q'} 
+ \sum_{p'=1}^p \sum_{q'=1}^q
{p\choose p'} {q\choose q'} (-1)^{p'+q'}
\\ = -1-1+1 = -1.$$

With $T$ empty (same with $S$ empty)

$$\sum_{p'=1}^p {p\choose p'} (-1)^{p'}  = -1.$$

We have  verified that the weight is  $-1$ in all cases  and hence the
answer is given by

$$(n^2)!
+ 2\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}^2 (-1)^k \times k! \times (n^2-kn)!
\\ + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n {n\choose k} {n\choose j}
(-1)^{k+j} (n^2-n(k+j)+kj)!.$$

This will produce the sequence

$$0, 13, 350314, 20907473410813, 15511088399276664432001386,
\\ 371993307691696427796897697438711091311473,
\\ 608281863896576961368925279207011528484342192328937893038299066,
\ldots $$

The Maple  code for  this was as  follows (warning,  total enumeration
only practicable for $n=2$ and $n=3$)

```
with(combinat);

Q :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local S, T, res, all, p, q;

    res := 0; all := powerset(n);

    for S in all do
        for T in all do
            p := nops(S); q := nops(T);

            if p = 0 and q = 0 then
                next;
            elif q = 0 then
                res := res +
                (-1)^p*binomial(n,p)*p!*(n^2-p*n)!;
            elif p = 0 then
                res := res +
                (-1)^q*binomial(n,q)*q!*(n^2-q*n)!;
            else
                res := res +
                (-1)^(p+q)*(n^2-((p+q)*n-p*q))!;
            fi;
        od;
    od;

    ((n^2)!) + res;
end;

X :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local perm, res, pos, rows, cols, srcrows, srccols;

    res := 0;

    srcrows :=
    {seq([seq(p*n+q+1, q=0..n-1)], p=0..n-1)};

    srccols :=
    {seq([seq(p*n+q+1, p=0..n-1)], q=0..n-1)};

    perm := firstperm(n^2);

    while type(perm, `list`) do

        rows :=
        {seq([seq(perm[p*n+q+1], q=0..n-1)], p=0..n-1)};

        cols :=
        {seq([seq(perm[p*n+q+1], p=0..n-1)], q=0..n-1)};

        if nops(rows intersect srcrows) = 0 and
        nops(cols intersect srccols) = 0 then
            res := res + 1;
        fi;

        perm := nextperm(perm);
    od;

    res;
end;

P :=
proc(n)
    (n^2)! + 2*add(binomial(n,k)^2*(-1)^k*k!*(n^2-k*n)!,
                   k=1..n)
    + add(add((-1)^(k+j)*binomial(n,k)*binomial(n,j)
              *(n^2-n*(k+j)+k*j)!, j=1..n),
          k=1..n);
end;
```

Comment: Why do "we  need to compute  the weight on  a configuration
that has exactly $p$ rows from  $A$ and $q$ columns"? Why is the first formula not enough?

Answer (score 1):

Since all of my mistakes and your one mistake have been corrected in the meantime, there's not much left to say here except that I believe the count is now correct.

Comment: The ${n \choose |I|}$ is for choosing $|I|$ rows from A that will appear in the matrix, and the $|I|! $ is the number of ways arranging them in the matrix

Comment: @guest: I see -- I'd overlooked that the rows/columns shouldn't be identical to *any* row/column, not just the corresponding ones. I've corrected the answer accordingly.

Comment: In the second displayed equation there are'nt ${n \choose |I|}$ and $|I|!$ because if for example the first row and the first column in the matrix are  identical to some row and some column in A, they must be the same as the first row and the first column in A (other options are not possible)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it

Comment: @joriki I couldn't get your formula from the intro to agree with my numbers posted below. Most likely I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Which formula are you referring to? The formula I originally posted was wrong, but I removed it quite a while ago. As far as I can tell, your result coincides with the one in the question. Where are you seeing a discrepancy?

Comment: @joriki Also with your $k$ rangeing to $2n$ you get factorials of negative numbers.

Comment: @joriki Again checking your $k$ we also get zero binomial coefficients.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: You're right about the factorials. The first term only needs to be summed to $n$; I thought that it's harmless to extend the sum to $2n$ (I think the OP did this in order to be able to write both sums in one) because the binomial coefficients in the superfluous terms are zero, but you're right that the negative factorials are undefined. Anyway, this is just a formal problem; I think the result (without the superfluous terms) coincides with yours?

Comment: Well of course Maple will produce an error if negative factorials appear, your binomial coefficients are fine. I entered your formula into Maple before I started the computation but even the modified version with $k$ rangeing to $n$ does not agree with what I have. I get the value $16$ for $n=2$ and the others differ as well. The undisputed wizard on inclusion-exclusion is @BrianMScott.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: You can't just cut the sum at $k=n$, since the second term has non-zero terms with $k\gt n$. But that term also has negative factorials for $k\gt n$ -- so if you don't want to define zero times negative factorial as zero, this whole approach doesn't work. Note by the way that in my own answer (in the edit history) I said that I prefer to work with symmetric summation indices for the rows and columns, like in your answer -- but I deleted that answer because it contained another (unrelated) mistake. So this isn't my answer, I just agreed that it's correct...

Comment: ... and I still think that it is if we drop the terms with binomial coefficients zero.

Comment: @joriki Good news! I redefined negative factorials as zero and extended the summation back to $2n$ and I obtained the same sequence as what I have (Maple). So it looks like my computation is correct, as is yours. I hope people will see this exchange when they try to work with the formula from the introduction.