# Counting number of matrices so that...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ be a matrix in which every number $1, 2, ... , n^2$ appears exactly one time.

Count the number of matrices $B$ (size $n\times n$) in which every number $1, 2, ... , n^2$ appears exactly one time, that doesn't share any row with $A$ (i.e, every row of $B$ is diffrent from all the rows of $A$).

I've tried the inclusion-exclusion principle but it didn't work.
Also tried finding a recurrence realtion.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This would appear to have a close match at the following [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826109/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of matrices $B$ with entries $1, \ldots, n^2$ that have at least a specified set of $k$ rows that are rows of $A$ is $$\dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!} (n^2-nk)!$$
Now use inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Oh, OK. My inclusion-exclusion was without the word "specified"