# Combinatorics Inclusion-Exclusion problem with matrix

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Let A $\in$ $M_{n}$ (a matrix) with the numbers 1, 2, ..., $n^2$ in it (each number appears once).

How many matrices B $\in$ $M_{n}$ with each of the numbers 1, 2,..., $n^2$ once there are such that there is no row in B which is the same like some row in A.

I saw similar question here: [Inclusion–exclusion: Matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826109/inclusion-exclusion-matrices][1])
 which also involves columns, but I dont need the columns restriction and the answer given there is not using inclusion-exclusion and not so clear to me.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the row in $B$ can't be the same like some row in $A$? Do you mean that they can't be exactly the same? Or that that they can't have any common elements? Just looking for a little clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take is that when you say that no row of $B$ is the same as (not "same like") some row of $A$ you mean that if the fourth row of $B$ is the same as the first row of $A$, then $B$ is excluded.

This is a straightforward application of inclusion-exclusion; we simply have to count how many $n\times n$ matrices with the elements $1,2,\dots,n^2$ have $k$ rows in common with $A$.  There are ${n\choose k}$ ways to choose which rows of $A$ occur in $B$, and ${n\choose k}$ places they can occur in $B$.  They can be arranged in $B$ in $k!$ orders.  There remain $n^2-kn$ elements in B, and these can be arranged in $(n^2-kn)!$ ways, so altogether we have $${n\choose k}^2k!(n^2-kn)!$$ ways.

I don't think you'll have any trouble completing it from here.

Comment: I tried to go in a way that my sets are all the matrices that the i-th row is as the same as some row in A, is that wrong way? 
The answer I got to is ($n^2$)! + $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}^2 \cdot k! \cdot (n^2 - kn)!$

Comment: That's the answer I get.